# Database design for annual payments

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I currently have two tables in my database:

- "customers" with the columns: customer_id, customer_name
- "payments" with the columns: payment_id, customer_id, year, paid
  (bool), payer

The column "year" indicates the year for which the "payer" has paid.

This gives me only one paid column:

```
SELECT customer_id, paid AS paid_for_2017 FROM customers LEFT JOIN payments ON customers.customer_id=payments.customer_id AND year=2017;
```

Now I need a SELECT query which gives me the following:

```
customer_name, paid_for_2017, paid_for_2018,...
```

How do I do this? Should I change my database design? Suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the years, you can just use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT customer_id,
       SUM(CASE WHEN year = 2017 THEN paid END) AS paid_for_2017,
       SUM(CASE WHEN year = 2018 THEN paid END) AS paid_for_2018
FROM customers c LEFT JOIN
     payments p
     ON c.customer_id = p.customer_id
GROUP BY customer_id;
```